# Why break function is not working and program says it's out of loop?

Tags: python

My `break` function is not working even though it is in the loop. Please, someone, explain in detail, because I'm new to Python.

```
q1 = input('want a question?: ')
if q1 == 'yes':
    print("let's get started!, press enter")
    a1 = input()
else:
    print('why did you even start me ?!')
    break
```

Here I expect `break` to stop the program from going any further.

Comment: Did you try to read about what `break` does before coming here?

Answer (score 1):

[`break`](https://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) doesn't stop your program from going any further. It breaks out of a loop.

You may want [`sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit), e.g.

```py
import sys

sys.exit()
```

Comment: so I am trying to make a program that is asking you questions. But the problem is that if the user gives the wrong answer the program is supposed to repeat a function that will ask the user if he want to try again and I don't know a how to that

Comment: @nothing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Comment: @nothing, new questions should be asked as new questions, not as comments. But before you ask a question, make sure to search. For example, see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/354577).

Comment: ok thank you, I'm just new to StackOverflow and just learning how stuff works here